# Scroll bar on the right side of the text div is not visible. I am creating a layout like the image attached

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/P8g3C/

I am trying to create the layout above. I am not getting the scroll bar to the right side of the content.

Also, suggest if there is any alternate way which better than my current approach

My html code is

```
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="content">
    <div class="content-left">Menu</div>
    <div class="content-right">Content which should be scrollable</div>
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

My CSS is

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: aqua;
}

.content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 35px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.content-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height:100%;
    background-color: aquamarine;
}

.content-right{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:200px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    background-color:blanchedalmond;
}

.footer {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: It's because of your `position: fixed` attributes of `.content` and `.content-right`.

Comment: What would be the possible alternative for this then please..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just remove `width:100%` of `.content-right`:

**Update**:

Because you use absolute positiong for the `.content-right` we can just set the `left` and `right` for it to make the `width` dynamic:

```
.content-right{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  /* add this */
  right:0; 
  left:200px;    
  height:100%;    
  overflow:auto;
  background-color:blanchedalmond;
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/P8g3C/4/)

Comment: Worked like a charm, both the solutions. Thankyou King King

Comment: If i remove the width:100%; of .content-right, I am not able to see any background color being applied when i dont have any content in that div

Comment: @user2768369 because you use absolute positioning, it's much easy to achieve what you want, see this updated demo http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/P8g3C/4/

Comment: Wonderful. Got the desired result. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are assigning a `width` of 100% to `.content-right`, yet already occupy 200px with the menu column, hence pushing the scrollbar off.

Try this:

```
.content-right {
    width:calc(100% -200px);
}
```

Alternately, you can remove the `width` property altogether, as @King King suggested

Here's a [Fiddle of your original demo code](http://jsfiddle.net/timmah/P8g3C/1/) showing the fix in action.

Comment: Worked like a charm, both the solutions. Thankyou Timmah

Comment: And just one more doubt, is this optimal approach which I am using or is there a better workaround?

Comment: The simplest way is the remove the `width` property altogether, the next is to change the width value as @Annsh said, and lastly the `width:calc()` method effectively does the same thing, but there is a risk of low browser support in older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct a width of class .content-right{ width:61%;}. because you have give a width of 100% that why you are not able to see a overflow scroll.

Comment: Can I still have 200px width for .content-left?

Comment: yes you can but righside width is totalwidth - leftside width;